# What all jars are required for setting up AOP environment in spring?

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-aop

I want to create a user library which includes all jars that are required to support Spring AOP apart from standard spring jars.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it, but use regular dependency management, e.g. via Maven or Gradle. Don't create your own uber JARs, it is just ugly and intransparent.

Which JARs you need is described in the [Spring AOP manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html). I am not a Spring user myself, only an AspectJ user, but AFAIK for simple Spring AOP you do not need anything but `spring-aop.jar`. I could be mistaken, but maybe you just try. CGLIB support is already contained in `spring-core.jar`.

You only need more JARs if you wish to upgrade to full AspectJ support. Then you would need `spring-aspects.jar` and, depending on how you start your application, maybe `aspectjweaver.jar`.

Another idea: If you want to make life easier for yourself, maybe you want to use Spring Boot?